# How to handle special entity letters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC application, When I copy paste the characters like `–` and `’` in `textarea` and saving it to the database.

When I read the same from database to Textarea, it is rendered `â€“`.

Any Ideas?

Comment: What database platform are you using? What is its encoding set to? UTF-8 or something else? What code are you using to read and write?

Comment: Just replace those characters with regular - (dash) and ' (single quote instead of rounded quote).